# MySQL: группировка по географическим координатам

Tags: mysql

Таблицы с полями `id`, `lat`, `lng`

- `lat` - широта, географическая координата
- `lng` - долгота,
  географическая координата

Каждая строчка таблицы содержит точку на карте.

Нужно вывести группы точек с одинаковыми координатами, с количеством точек в группе не менее 10.

Comment: [Having][1] вам должен помочь

[1]:http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html

Comment: Пример можно увидеть? Иначе -- куча наводящих вопросов.

Comment: Сгруппируйте данные по координатам (GROUP BY), а затем выберите группы с количеством точек в группе не менее 10 (HAVING).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  lat,
  lng,
  COUNT(id) AS total
FROM
  coords
GROUP BY
  lat, lng
HAVING
  total > 10
```